# Immutable queue implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, queue

I created a queue in which we can perform Enqueue, Dequeue and Traversing in Scala.

```
class Queue[+A](list:List[A]) {
  def enqueue[B>:A](x:B):Queue[B]= new Queue[B](list :+ x)
  def dequeue[B>:A]:Queue[B] = new Queue[B](list.tail)
  def head = list.head
  def tail = list.tail
}
```

Please review this code and make suggestions.

Comment: Inside the [Scala language source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala), you can see how they implemented it. It can give you hints on how to refactor your class.